# How to run snowflake stored procedure asynchronously

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to execute a set of snowflake stored procedure in parallel. For example:

```
sp_test(1)
sp_test(2)
sp_test(3)
```

All three calls are not dependent on each other to finish. I need to execute all of them asynchronously.

Please suggest a way to achieve using snowflake task.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no ready-made method in Snowflake. This year there may be methods for executing async SQL stored procedures and methods in Snowpark Python, but they are not there yet.

At the moment, you can use external mechanisms, such as in python concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor, [Snowflake SQL REST API](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/sql-api/index) or in Snowflake create a dynamically [TASK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task) root and subtasks with calls to your procedures and then run the root task.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this (as of now) using snowflake task is by having each stored procedure in a different task and scheduling all 3 tasks to run at the same time.